# Horizontal bar with overflow hidden being weird

Tags: html, css

I made this bar (nav2) to be scrollable if it's not enough screen space, but it seems to be very weird (also because it's my first time I'm doing such thing as a horizontal scrollable bar), the ul is going somewhere in the top, and doesn't come down, I tried float: left, it works, but the ul is not centered in the middle (that's important!)

```css
body { font-family: 'Clear Sans', Verdana, sans-serif; margin: 0; }
    
    #nav1 {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    }
    
    #nav2 {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    overflow: scroll;
    
    }
    
    #nav3 {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 40px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    }
    
    
    #nav2 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    }
    
    #nav2 ul li {
    display: inline;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
    }
    
    #nav2 ul a {
    padding: 5px 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    }
    
    @keyframes sin {
      0% {transform: rotate(0deg)}
      100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
    }
    
    #yvelogo {
    margin-left: 17px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    }
    
    a #yvelogo {
    border: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>yvemiro</title>
      <meta name="author" content="hate">
      <meta name="description" content="description for gogel">
      <meta name="keywords" content="yve,miro,blog">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/zicio7x/hgpnuuz05/fonts.css" type="text/css">
     </head>
     <body>
      <div id="navbar">
      <div id="nav1"><a href="#"><img id="yvelogo" alt="eeh, is it IE or what" src="http://static.tumblr.com/zicio7x/VTfnvi4e4/yvelogowhite.svg"></a></div>
      <div id="nav2">
      <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li><li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li><li><a href="#">Me</a></li><li><a href="#">Ask</a></li><li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
      <div id="nav3"></div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You wouldn't really do that to your users, would you? Uggh.

Comment: `#nav2 ul { /* display: block; */  /* float: left; */ }` and `#nav2 { overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden; }` ?

Comment: @RedDevil -- I like your solution on {overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;}   as it removes the vertical scroll and makes a clean edge.  Still, {white-space: nowrap;} needs to be added so the unordered list items show up side-by-side.  Otherwise, list items start stacking up on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(

  function() { 

    $("#nav2").niceScroll();

  }

);
```

```css
body { font-family: 'Clear Sans', Verdana, sans-serif; margin: 0; }
    
    #nav1 {
    width: 33%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    }
    
    #nav2 {
    width: 34%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    #nav3 {
    width: 33%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: yellow;
      float: right;
    }
    
    
    #nav2 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    
    }
    
    #nav2 ul li {
    display: inline;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
    }
    
    #nav2 ul a {
    padding: 5px 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    }
    
    @keyframes sin {
      0% {transform: rotate(0deg)}
      100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
    }
    
    #yvelogo {
    margin-left: 17px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    }
    
    a #yvelogo {
    border: 0;
    }

    @media (max-width:990px) {
    #nav2 {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>yvemiro</title>
      <meta name="author" content="hate">
      <meta name="description" content="description for gogel">
      <meta name="keywords" content="yve,miro,blog">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/zicio7x/hgpnuuz05/fonts.css" type="text/css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js">
         </script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div id="navbar">
      <div id="nav1"><a href="#"><img id="yvelogo" alt="eeh, is it IE or what" src="http://static.tumblr.com/zicio7x/VTfnvi4e4/yvelogowhite.svg"></a></div>
      <div id="nav2">
      <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li><li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li><li><a href="#">Me</a></li><li><a href="#">Ask</a></li><li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
      <div id="nav3"></div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

This should fix it up a bit. If you NEED vertical centering, I can revise it once more.

Edit:
Added custom scrollbar plugin and jquery. More information about editing the scrollbar itself can be found at the plugin's official website [Here](http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/)

Comment: It works, but! The thing is, that I also need a normal (custom) scrollbar with a style, because the that Windows has is ugly and out of the context. I've seen all those scrollbars on pseudoclasses (or whatever), but it also apparently adds space in the bottom, so it's very specific. Any suggestions how I can realize it here?

Comment: @yve Yea, I can do that. The problem is, most browsers don't support plain css scrollbars. I'll include a nice jquery plugin for you and an example scrollbar

Comment: Good, but please, as little code as possible (I'm a big fan of that rule), thank you :-)

Comment: Okay, I'll just link it to an external JS file and add a tiny bit of css

Comment: Hi, I tweaked it for my needs, but the padding for the <a> is really picky, 9px has a little gap, that is visible when link turns :hover, 10px is too much, that it enables the vertical scroll, what do I do?? http://codepen.io/yvem/pen/6ac059d42ace4b6a73705abc81688717/

Comment: But I don't think the transition is working, instead of using a decimal and seconds, u should declare it in milliseconds: ms rather than s.

Comment: Also, add -webkit-transition

Answer (score 1):

**'float: left;'** will align your divs (nav1, nav2, nav3) side-by-side inside 'navbar', unless you want them side by side.

'navbar' does not have a top margin.  Therefore, it aligns itself all the way on top.  If you want the navbar to go down a bit, you will need to create a class or div inside your .css file, and give it a top margin.

I have changed your 'nav2' css values as follows:

```
#nav2 ul {  
    width: calc(100% / 3);  
    height: 80px;  /* changed 40px to 80px */
    background-color: red;  
    float: left;
    overflow-x: auto; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; /* added nowrap */  
}
```

If you double the number of your unordered list items, you will see what I mean.

Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: Thanks, it works, the solution Andrew Robinson suggested works pretty much the same way. I wrote a thing in the comments to his post, you can check and help, if you want.